# Can I use the cookie c_user set by facebook?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Can I use cookie named `c_user` which contains the `userid` of facebook users who logged in?
If it can be accessed by facebook php api, please provide me link.

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
```

Few suggested to use this above code to get session, but this function is not defined in `facebook-php-sdk`.

Please show me a way to get user id of user currently logged in.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> *Please show me a way to get user id of user currently logged in.*

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
  alert('Your id is ' + response.id);
});
```