# Whats is the use of this facebook function?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to figure out the id of facebook user currently logged in.

I used this code but I'm getting error.

```
$facebook = new Facebook_php_sdk(array(
    'appId'  => '226568227411676',
    'secret' => '68bdfeb63d01e8122ed0a46d8fd5dfc1'
));

$rr = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$token = array(
    'access_token' => $rr
);

$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET',$token);
```

on this I am getting error saying `"Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"`.

Comment: you should have updated your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740345/can-i-use-cookie-c-user-set-by-facebook) instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 1):

This error occured because you trying to access user's information, using Application access token. [Details here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)